# Ruby: Assign output of a function only if it does not return nil

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

When programming in Ruby I quite often have assignments like the following

```
test = some_function if some_function
```

With that assignments I want to assign the output of a function, but if it returns `nil` I want to keep the content of the variable. I know there are conditional assignments, but neither `||=` nor `&&=` can be used here. The shortest way I found to describe the statement above is

```
test = (some_function or test)
```

Is there a better / shorter way to do this?

Comment: It was important as I used the first version until recently and that evaluates the function twice. The second version thus is better. As I have to replace the first version throughout my code I just wanted to make sure that I replace it with the best way to handle this - or maybe a best practice.

Comment: For me it was worth asking the question as I got an answer which told me three things I didn't know about that simple expression. First, use `||` instead of `or`. Second, consider using `presence`. Third, think about the functional approach. That's more than I had hoped for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's anything better than the last snippet you showed but note that `or` is used for flow control, use `||` instead:

```
test = some_function || test
```

It's usually better to assign new values to new names, the resulting code is easier to understand and debug since variables/symbols have the same value throughout the scope:

```
some_different_and_descriptive_name_here = some_function || test
```

Comment: With several more years of experience I can confirm that my answer was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just add parentheses

> > `(a = b) unless b.nil?`
> >
> > `(a = b) if b`

being inferior because if b is false then a remains as before

Keep in mind that this evaluates b twice, so if b is a function with side-effects (such as changing variables outside of its scope or printing) it will do that twice; to avoid this you must use

> > `temp = b; (a = temp) unless temp.nil?`

(which can, of course, be split into)

> > `temp = b`
> >
> > `(a = temp) unless temp.nil?`